# How to replace a particular text filed in json file if that text field has multiple ocurrances using inbuilt unix tools

Tags: json, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a json file where i need to change some key:values. The Key and values are dynamic and are stored in a array. I just need to parse the file and replace value corresponding to the particular key.

```
foo="user"
cat properties.json | jq '.node.${foo}' > tempo.json
```

So if i tried the following command errors are thrown ..

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.master_node.$foo
jq: 1 compile error
```

Tried lot of commands.. But i could not pass variable while traversing a json tree.. Appreciate any help

Comment: How are line ends used? is there one node by line? What characters are used for usernames / passwords?

Comment: there are one nodes per line..Username and password can have any character..Dont know how line ends are used..probably new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), like this:

```
jq --arg flag "node2" \
   --argjson input '{"user": "jack","password": "killbie"}' \
'(.[$flag]|.user)|=$input.user|(.[$flag]|.password)|=$input.password' your.json
```

Comment: Why are you looking for those? Don't use `sed` or `awk` for that. These tools can't reliably solve this. (Even if others might post some hackish answers. Trust me). I recommend to a) install `jq` or b) use a programming language that can deal with json and is installed on any linux distribution, like Python2

Comment: @BeatrixKiddo if I were you, I will take hek2mgl's advice.  He can certainly post sed/awk solutions, (check his reputation & his profile), but he's chosen `jq` tool, because it is the right way. Same for Xml/html parsing, first thing is, choose the right tool.

Comment: @hek2mgl and Kent thanks for your suggestion. I too came to the same conclusion. I just thought there may be some solution available..Anyway  thanks again..

Comment: @hek2mgl what to do if "input"  in --argjson is not hardcoded and it is in some file or any other variable ?

Comment: When it is a another variable, use that variable. When it is in another file, use `--argfile input FILENAME.json`

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't post code in comments

Comment: Please take a little moment and read the formatting help to make the code in the answer nicely formatted and indented. That's your part of work, I'll try to answer then

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks a lot for your help. I solved my problem.Your first solution works for me.I was doing some syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to change every user and password, regardless of the node name, you could just use sed:

```
cat file.json | sed "s/\"user\": \"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\", /\"user\": \"jack\", /" | sed "s/\"password\": \"[0-9a-zA-Z@]*\", /\"password\": \"killbie\", /"
```

Keep in mind that you need to specify the character group to match (`[0-9a-zA-Z@]`), in this case I have put characters I saw in your example.

In case you need to replace it only for some nodes, or do some more complicated conditions, then you might need a specific json analyzer tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) (outside the scope of "inbuilt unix tools") or some higher level scripting language like python (possibly inline python like [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/3271507)). Doing it with sed would only work as long as the node name and the attributes are in the same line. I'd do it with backreferences (`\1`, `\3`). Here's an example:

```
sed "s/\(node2.*\)\(\"user\": \"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\", \)\(.*\)}/\1\"user\": \"jack\", \3/"
```

Comment: thanks for the sugesstion . Is there any reg ex to identify the required term ..here "user" which is inbetween "node2" and "}"  ?